# How to user-input an object property and key

Tags: javascript, html

I have in my hand, a very rare problem. I need the user to input an object's key and property.

I have an `input`.

```
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="enter">
```

my js:
Take text inputed, and store it in `var input`.
Like for example, if user inputs "hello" then...

```
var myObj = {
  hello: "hello"
}
```

Is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation:

If you are storing the input in a variable named input you would do this:

```
var myObj = {};
obj[input] = input;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with literal notation?

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/mjjLxqnr/3/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="yourInput">
<input type="button" value="Enter" id="enterBtn">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var obj = {},
    enterBtn = document.getElementById('enterBtn'),
    yourInput = document.getElementById('yourInput');

enterBtn.onclick = function () {
    var input = yourInput.value;
    // Don't add anything to the obj if the input is empty.
    if(!input) return;
    // Use brackets to add a property to the obj, and set the value to be the same
    // as the property name.
    obj[input] = input;
    console.log(obj);
};
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was my original question, but I was alerted that my question wasn't  well understood. So I changed it. Sorry.